# Physic simulation is visible in viewport, but not in the animation render

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, force-fields, rigidbody

My physics animation is working as expected while I'm inside Blender. When I try to render the animation, the simulation is not running. Every frame is identical (the objects are static).

Viewport:

[image]

Render:

[image]

[image]
blender file

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on your setup, or post some screenshots or even a .blend file so users have a better chance to help you?

Comment: please use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for uploading blend files. Thanks

Comment: @Timaroberts thank you for the heads up!

Comment: It's not clear what's yours final objective. In your blend file the objects are moving..

Comment: @Sanbaldo i'm trying to export it into an mp4 video, but the pieces won't move

Comment: @Sanbaldo I'm confused about why you removed all the pictures?

Comment: images were not bringing any useful information to the question/problem.

Comment: @Sanbaldo a) You need to '@' someone for them to be notified of your comment b) I disagree. We generally always want to see images and then only as a last resort have a look at a blend file.

Comment: @RayMairlot, I just proposed the edit of the question (I don't have rights to edit yet) to make it clean and don't distract readers with not "useful" images. But I get your point.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cache the physic animation:

1. Go to *Scene Properties*.
2. Go to *Rigid Body World*.
3. Under *Cache*, *delete all bakes* and then click on *Bake All Dynamics*.
4. You can now render your video.

[image]